# CSS Priority and Hierarchy

Tags: css, visual-studio, properties

This will probably be an extremely easy question to answer, but I am trying to create a one-stop-shop for setting up property values from SQL and would like to know an answer to the issue that just came up in brainstorming:

If you set a parent (let's say a form) to be Read-Only but set an object (lets say a button) in that parent to NOT be Read-Only, will the button be read-only? Also, what If the parent or child had !Important included?

I am trying to set up a priority system so users can set up these kind of property values without running into issues where unexpected things do not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readonly` is not a css property, thus no style. It goes directly into the html tag.

The key buzzwords for you to search are `css inheritance` and `css specifity`.

For a quick overview: Yes, there are fixed rules. Not every property is inherited. You can look them up e.g. in the [MDN CSS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference).
Which css rule kicks in depends on where you place the style rules and how specific your selector is.

Cascading order [(source)](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp):

1. Inline style (inside an HTML element)
2. External and internal style sheets (in the head section)
3. Browser default

Specifity is like a score system. The rule with the highest score (=highest specifity) applies.

1. ID, e.g. `#paragraph {...}` (100 points)
2. Class, e.g. `.redparagraphs {...}` (10 points)
3. Tag, e.g. `p {...}` (1 point)

So the rule `div p span {...}` would have a score of 3 points, because of three tag selectors.
`#wrapper .centered #main .fancynews .withoutborder p {...}` would have 231 points and so on.

If two rules have the same score (specifity), then the last one processed counts (stylesheets are processed from top to bottom).

The "quick and dirty" trick for applying a style is to add an `!important` to the rule like

```
.alwaysredtext { color:#F00 !important; }
```

This will override whatever color rule you made and whereever (as long as they do not also have an `!important`). This is not recommended due to later maintainability problems.

p.s.: Don't miss the [Specifity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) where you can enter and compare several selector rules and see which one "wins".

Answer (score 0):

Only `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements support the `readonly` attribute, so not, what you are describing is not possible.

Comment: What about Visible? Or other aspects, like background color or something that can be shared between a parent and child like scenario?